# When I use topic/subscription in Azure Service Bus, is it possible to call an web api to inform me to get the message? Like AWS SNS

Tags: azure, servicebus

As I know, in AWS, if there's a new message in queue, AWS SNS can call my web API to inform me to get the message, so I don't need to get message by polling the queue to check if there is new message. Does Azure Service Bus topic/subscription has this similar function? Or I only can get the message by polling the subscription to check if there are new messages? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not via Web API, but via .NET client library. This is named there the "Event Driven Programming model". And is in .NET Client library since April'2013. You can read more here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn198643.aspx
and here
http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/introducing-the-event-driven-message-programming-model-for-the-windows-azure-service-bus/

Comment: Hi astaykov, thanks very much. It seems this is in .Net SDK, I want to use Azure Java SDK, how can I do it?

Comment: It still uses polling internally though - there is no push notification feature built into Azure Service Bus as far as I know.